# Notice: Trying to get property 'term_id' of non-object

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, terms, notices, term-meta

I receive the error on taxonomy page in wp-admin.Before this error, I had problem that couldnt add the taxonomy to menu because of my taxonomy code.I fixed the code then the current error became.So, How to fix it? Thanks

```
Notice: Trying to get property 'term_id' of non-object in /home/deniztas/oneclick.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-terms-list-table.php on line 420

Notice: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in /home/deniztas/oneclick.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-terms-list-table.php on line 421

Notice: Trying to get property 'slug' of non-object in /home/deniztas/oneclick.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-terms-list-table.php on line 424

Notice: Trying to get property 'parent' of non-object in /home/deniztas/oneclick.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-terms-list-table.php on line 425
turkey

Notice: Trying to get property 'query_var' of non-object in /home/deniztas/oneclick.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 4218


    Notice: Trying to get property 'term_id' of non-object in /home/deniztas/oneclick.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-terms-list-table.php on line 420

    Notice: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in /home/deniztas/oneclick.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-terms-list-table.php on line 421

    Notice: Trying to get property 'slug' of non-object in /home/deniztas/oneclick.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-terms-list-table.php on line 424

    Notice: Trying to get property 'parent' of non-object in /home/deniztas/oneclick.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-terms-list-table.php on line 425
    turkey

    Notice: Trying to get property 'query_var' of non-object in /home/deniztas/oneclick.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 4218
```

Thanks to @Tom J Nowell or Captain one eye as popular name in this community, I fixed it.The answer so its the changing in code:

> ```
> I've identified two issues, the first, this:
>
>             'rewrite' => true,
>             'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'districts' ),
> Can just be this:
>
>             'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'districts' ),
> And the second, the reason you get invalid menu items, is because districts is being used as the rewrite slug, but, the internal namevof
> ```
>
> the taxonomy is Districts.
>
> ```
> Replacing Districts with districts as the internal name fixed the issue for me locally:
>
> register_taxonomy( 'districts', array('post'), array(
> It's a general rule of thumb to keep internal names of things lower case, you can always use the labels for what the user sees
> ```

Comment: This is probably related to terms in the database having `District` rather than `district`, you might need to recreate and reassign those terms, then delete the originals. Also my eyes work fine, I just pulled a funny face for my avatar

Comment: @TomJNowell yes, I deleted some infos from wpgy_terms and it works now.Also I am happy for your eye's health

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted problematic entries from wpgy_terms on database then it works now.If you are new at database, I suggest that backup your database before do something on it.